# How does a method get called twice?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning swift and have the following methods in a class:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return countries.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text =  countries[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

This is puzzling to me as I have not programmed before where I can have a method (i.e. tableView) that can be called twice. How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by called twice? You want to call twice a method? Or is it because `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called twice? It's called every time it needs to be, like anytime a cell has to be displayed.

Comment: Well, tableView appears twice as a method. I do not understand how this is possible. If I create a function named myFunc, I cannot create another function named myFunc can I?

Comment: Well, in a certain way you can. If you translate to Objective-C, as I'm not that familiar with Swift, you have two methods: `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. So they aren't the same. It's just the Swift way of declaration that may lure you into being the same methods when it is not.

Comment: The first thing you need to learn about `xcode` is that it is an IDE and not a programming language, this has absolutely nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` I have removed the tag and changed references to `xcode` to `swift`

Comment: In the materials I have been using to learn Swift, people so often refer back to Objective C, but I don't want to learn to program in Objective C, I want to learn to program in Swift. The introductory materials present programming in Swift in a manner that is very similar to ActionScript3 or Javascript, but I could not use a method in this manner in ActionScript, so I am wondering how to conceptualize these method calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not think of the method as being defined only by the name before the parenthesis.  If the arguments are different, then it is a completely different method.

Answer (score 1):

These are not method calls; these are function definitions. However, because they share the same function name, they cannot be invoked without specifying the parameter names. Invoking them would be done as such (though it's done internally in `UITableView`, so you don't have to worry about it in this particular case):

```
tableView(theTableView, numberOfRowsInSection:theSection);
tableView(theTableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath);
```

Note that `section` and `indexPath` are the names used internally by the function for the external parameter names `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, respectively.

For more information on function names, parameters, and general structure of the signatures, refer to the Swift documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_598